# Volume of deformed sphere

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]
I tried using spherical coordinates but couldn't figure out the bounds. 3D graphing doesnt work for this function

Answer (score 2):

Here's the volume:

[image]

Use symmetry and thus just consider the volume in the positive octant:

[image]

Now the integral is simple:

$$V = 8 \int\limits_{x=0}^1 \int\limits_{y=0}^{\sqrt{1 - \sqrt{x}}} \int\limits_{z=0}^{(1 - \sqrt{x} - y^2)^2}\!\!\!\!\!\!\! 1\ dx\ dy\ dz = \frac{512}{945}$$